# "Exception from Tracker recompute function: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined" - Meteor and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I'm using [dburles:google-maps](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNnOT72dbTAhUHxpAKHRPWCVgQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdburles%2Fmeteor-google-maps&usg=AFQjCNHsNxjoG2YjnST7w3HC5Sh53jFcNw&sig2=div42RfmmFajqUH3Otrzag) in my Meteor app. I have a collection called `recorridos`, where each document has a two arrays (`ida` and `vuelta`) of objects `{lat: xxx, lng: yyy}`. I'm retrieving one doc from the collection, and I'm creating two PolyLine's and setting them to the instance of the map, with a switch to alternate between `ida` and `vuelta`.
It works fine, but sometimes, when I reload the page I get the following error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (recorrido-mapa.js:28)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2271)
    at viewAutorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1931)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:339)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:358)
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:523)
    at onGlobalMessage (meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:401)
```

This is the code:

recorridos-mapa.js

```
// Packages
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { GoogleMaps } from 'meteor/dburles:google-maps';

import './recorrido-mapa.html';

// Components
import '../../components/map/map.js';
import '../../components/linea-card/linea-card.js';

// Methods
import { getRecorrido } from '../../../api/recorridos/methods.js';

var idaPath, vueltaPath, map, IdaStartPoint, idaEndPoint, startMarker, endMarker;

Template.Recorrido_mapa.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(() => {
        var subscription = this.subscribe('recorridos');
        console.log(subscription.ready());
        if(subscription.ready()) {
            // Obtenemos la linea de los queryParams y llamamos a metodo para obtener recorrido
            linea = parseInt(FlowRouter.getQueryParam("linea"));
            res = getRecorrido.call(linea);

            // Si recibimos datos del metodo, instanciamos marcadores y polilineas para mapa
            map = GoogleMaps.maps.colesMap.instance;

            idaStartPoint   = res.ida[0];
            idaEndPoint         =   res.ida[res.ida.length - 1];

            vueltaStartPoint = res.vuelta[res.vuelta.length - 1];
            vueltaEndPoint   =  res.ida[0];

            // Marker de start
            startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                label: "I"
            });
            startMarker.setMap(map);

            //Marker de end
            endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                label: "F"
            });
            endMarker.setMap(map);

            // Polilineas de recorrido
            idaPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: res.ida,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#26a69a',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 3
            });

            vueltaPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: res.vuelta,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#9d1322',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 3
            });

            setIdaVuelta(idaStartPoint, idaEndPoint, idaPath, vueltaPath);
        }
    });
});

Template.Recorrido_mapa.events({
    'change #switch-ida-vuelta': function(event) {
        let checked = event.target.checked;
        if(!checked)
            setIdaVuelta(idaStartPoint, idaEndPoint, idaPath, vueltaPath);
        else
            setIdaVuelta(vueltaStartPoint, vueltaEndPoint, vueltaPath, idaPath);
    }
});

function setIdaVuelta(startPoint, endPoint, pathShow, pathHide) {
    startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
    endMarker.setPosition(endPoint);
    pathShow.setMap(map);
    pathHide.setMap(null);
}
```

recorrido.js

```
// Main Template
import './recorridos.html'

// Componentes
import '../../components/linea-card/linea-card.js'

// Methods
import { getLineas } from '../../../api/lineas/methods.js'

// Helpers
Template.Recorridos_page.helpers({
    lineas() {
        res = getLineas.call().fetch()
        return res
    }
})

Template.Linea_card.events({
    "click .list": function(event, template) {
        let l = template.data.lineas
        FlowRouter.go('/recorridos/mapa?linea=' + l.numero)
    }
})

Template.Recorridos_page.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('lineas')
    })
})
```

And this is the markup:

recorridos.html

```
<template name="Recorridos_page">
    {{> Navbar main_title="Recorridos"}}
    <div style="padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        {{#each l in lineas}}
            {{> Linea_card notUnique=true lineas=l}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

recorridos-mapa.html

```
<template name="Recorrido_mapa">
    {{> Map}}
    {{> Linea_card  notUnique=false}}
</template>
```

I really want to understand why this Exception is being trhow sometimes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map = GoogleMaps.maps.colesMap.instance;`
Is where the error is pointing. I would guess that the page is rendering before the GoogleMaps.maps has been initiated/loaded completely.

If you share the map setup code I can perhaps give you a specific example.

Comment: Yes! You pointed me in the right direction. I used the `GoogleMaps.ready('nameOfInstance', callback)` function. I made the setting of markers and polylines inside the `callback` and now the exception is not triggering anymore. 
I don't know if to accept your answer as the correct though, but sure you help me!